# Wordpress Relative Path

Tags: multi-language, paths

I have multisite blog for 2 languages, and I want to easily switch it.

```
www.example.com/page/post
```

I would like to switch to

```
www.example.com/english/page/post
```

I have **get_blog_option(2, 'siteurl')** which returns `www.example.com/english/`
but I cant find any function which returns only `/page/post/`

I have one which returns `www.example.com/page/post` but how put there `/english/` inside

Thanks

Comment: not an answer if your site is already live but qtranslate does just this in 1 blog: wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/

Comment: I know but client want two sites for two office

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`get_blog_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_permalink)